# Remove ith row of a matrix. i varies from 1 to number of rows in data matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I want to remove each row of a matrix, one by one. First I remove the first row, run my function, then I want to get back the first row but remove the 2nd row, and so on. It's just like when what we do in calculating Jackknife.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this idea:

```
> mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)                 # create a matrix
> lapply(1:nrow(mat), function(i) mat[-i,])  # creating a list of matrices leaving-one-out
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    3    6    9

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
```